# How to target a group of controls in a storyboard WPF

Tags: wpf, storyboard

```
<Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="{StaticResource test}"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 From="1"
                 To="0"
                 RepeatBehavior="2000"
                 AutoReverse="True"
                 Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
</Storyboard>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Loaded" SourceName="button">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Button x:Name="button2" x:key="test"  Content="Button" Margin="234,140,164,0" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Button x:Name="button3" x:key="test"  Content="Button" Margin="234,140,164,0" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I am trying to add this double animation to multiple buttons without duplicating the double animation. Initially, I had the TargetName set to the name of the first button and it works but if added key to the button I get this message "The property "key" does not exist in WinFX namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give ButtonA the storyboard that drives its Opacity. For each other button,

```
<Button
    x:Name="button3"
    Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=button2}"
    ...
    />
```

Alternatively, put all the buttons inside a StackPanel (or Grid, or whatever), and animate the parent's `Opacity`.

Comment: I didn't understand. I have not come across element name as yet. What is ButtonA? what does it refer to?

Comment: @Decoder94 See update. I changed `ButtonA` to `button2` since that's a name you actually used in your sample. What that `ElementName` thing does it it uses that XAML element as a source. The effect is that whenever `button2.Opacity` changes, the opacity of `button3` will be automatically updated to have the same value.

Comment: Thanks. Understood!

Answer (score 1):

The sample markup you have posted doesn't provide a reproducible sample of your issue but you could add a trigger to each `Button` that you want to animate:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
            <DoubleAnimation
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 From="1"
                 To="0"
                 RepeatBehavior="2000"
                 AutoReverse="True"
                 Duration="0:0:0.7"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```